# error in selecting particular columns from one csv file and writing to another in python

Tags: python, csv

I have a csv file which has about 60 columns. I want to select column `2`,`11`, and then all the columns from `25` onwards till the last column. I wrote this short code but this is giving me error as: `TypeError: cannot concatenate 'str' and 'list' objects`.

```
file_read = open('file1.csv', mode='r')
file_write = open('file2.csv', mode ='w')
reader = csv.reader(file_read)
writer = csv.writer(file_write)

for row in reader:

    writer.writerow(row[2] + row[11] + row[25:])

file_write.close()
```

I know its because of using `row[25:]` along with other particular columns but how can else I write this?

**PS:** Pardon me for lack on understanding in python as I am learning it

Answer (score 2, accepted):

`row[25:]` is a list - a slice from a `row` list, `row[2]` and `row[11]` are strings - this is why you are getting the `TypeError: cannot concatenate 'str' and 'list' objects`.

Instead, "concatenate" lists:

```
writer.writerow([row[2]] + [row[11]] + row[25:])
```